# Disable Ctrl+Shift+S in Skype for Business

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, skype-for-business

we are using Skype for Business for collaboration. We use Visual Studio for development.

Both Skype and VS has key bindings for **Ctrl+Shift+S**.

- VS => Save all files.
- Skype => End current presentation.

It is very annoying to end presentation when we are just saving files we just collaborated on.

I have tried to create string value **CtrlShiftS** in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\Lync\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes` key with 17,16,83 value.

It did not help.

Please help!

Comment: Seamed to be an issue since a very long time (see [here](http://lync.ideascale.com/a/dtd/Ability-to-manage-Hotkeys/450499-16285)). Did you tried the solution mentioned in that article for example the ones [here](http://superuser.com/questions/797337/disable-controlenter-when-typing-a-message-in-lync) or [here](http://lyncvoice.blogspot.de/2016/08/skype-for-business-custom-shortcuts.html). P.S. thats not a developer question which are handled on StackOverflow. A better community might be [Superuser](http://superuser.com).